# JSF How to evaluate c:set only once at declaration place

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I was using `c:set` as expression alias. Today I encountered, that `c:set` is evaluated everytime **var** is being used and also on each "invocation" it's output changes - depends on current context:

```
<!-- lets say composite has id "composite" -->
<ui:composition ...>
    <cc:implementation>
        <c:set var="compositeClientId" value="#{component.namingContainer.clientId}"/> 

        <!-- OUTPUTS "composite" -->
        <h:outputText value="#{compositeClientId}"/>       

        <h:form id="form">
            <!-- OUTPUTS "composite:form" -->
            <h:outputText value="#{compositeClientId}"/>    
        </h:form>
    <cc:implementation>    
</ui:composition>
```

Is there any way, how to evaluate `c:set` at declaration place so in both cases it would output "composite"?

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, why don't you use `#{cc.clientId}` instead? It's already internally cached in `UIComponent`

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for pointing`#{cc.clientId}` out, didn't notice :).